# Quando e perché il termine “extracomunitario” ha assunto una connotazione negativa?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage

Treccani, come tutti gli altri dizionari, da le seguenti definizioni del termine

***extracomunitario***;

> - agg. e s. m. [comp. di extra- e comunitario (cfr. comunità, n. 2 a)]. – Che non fa parte dell’Unione Europea: paesi e,
> - come sost., spec. al plur. masch., gli e., coloro che emigrano da paesi economicamente disagiati (spec. da regioni dell’Africa e dell’Asia) negli stati dell’Unione Europea in cerca di lavoro e di migliori condizioni di vita.

La seconda definizione, con connotazione spesso negativa,  è senza dubbio la più comune e diffusa nel linguaggio contemporaneo.

Da [Parlarecivile.it](http://www.parlarecivile.it/argomenti/immigrazione/extracomunitario.aspx):

> È ormai assodato che questa parola ha una forte connotazione negativa, come si evince anche dalla definizione aggiornata del vocabolario Treccani. Infatti non verrebbe mai definito ‘extracomunitario’ uno svizzero o un americano, anche se tecnicamente lo sono.

Quando e perché il termine comincia ad essere  impropriamente usato fino a diventare, per alcuni, quasi un'offesa?

Comment: Potresti portare qualche fonte dell'uso negativo o offensivo? La voce di dizionario che citi non mi sembra che ne rechi traccia ed è il termine “neutro” usato in ambito giornalistico e burocratico. Poi, certo, qualunque termine si può usare come se fosse un insulto se uno discrimina una certa categoria di esseri umani: donna, africano, vecchio, laziale...

Comment: Forse la connotazione "negativa" fa riferimento soltanto al fatto di provenire da un paese povero (cioè, per esempio, di solito non si usa "extracomunitario" per qualificare un turista che viene da un paese ricco).

Comment: Non è una novità che i nomi di gruppi etnici di immigrati siano usati con connotazione negativa: prima di "extracomunitario" c'erano "terrone", "zingaro", ecc.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: È diverso: “terrone” è un nomignolo creato apposta dai settentrionali per irridere i meridionali, e lo status della parola “zingaro” (rispetto a quelle indicano specifiche etnie come i rom e i sinti) è molto complesso. Di “extracomunitario” invece non mi risulta un esteso uso offensivo (salvo il fatto che ovviamente se uno vuole offendere può farlo con qualsiasi parola del vocabolario).

Comment: Posso confermare che in Veneto "extracomunitario" è un insulto, usato più o meno come sinonimo di "negro" e "marocchino" (e sì, la maggior parte degli extracomunitari non viene dal Marocco, ma che posso dirvi, gli insulti provinciali sono fatti così)